# unable to decode "kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": no kind "Role" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"

Tags: kubernetes

could anyone help me with K8s dashboarding problem as below:

```
flag needs an argument: 'f' in -f[root@localhost ~]# kubectl apply -f kubernetes-dashboard.yaml 
secret "kubernetes-dashboard-certs" configured
serviceaccount "kubernetes-dashboard" configured
service "kubernetes-dashboard" configured
unable to decode "kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": no kind "Role" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"
unable to decode "kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": no kind "RoleBinding" is registered for version "rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1"
unable to decode "kubernetes-dashboard.yaml": no kind "Deployment" is registered for version "apps/v1"
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means either your kubernetes version is too old or RBAC API is not enabled in your cluster.

You can check `<apiserver_ip>:<apiserver_port>/apis` endpoint. If you use `kubectl proxy` then check `http://localhost:8001/apis`. It should list enabled apis and their versions. You can use that information to adjust deploy yaml.

If RBAC API is not enabled you need to enable it and the process depends on how you installed the cluster.